# Spacer between tabs in Extjs

Tags: extjs

How to add spacer element or someting like that between tabs? I need to seperate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{
   xtype: 'tbfill'
}
```

or

```
{
    xtype: 'tbspacer'
}
```

or

```
{
    xtype: 'tbseparator'
}
```

Comment: That's for toolbars, not tabs

Answer (score 3):

Just use margin at tabConfig.
If you want 20px left side of tab, try 
`tabConfig: {
xtype: 'tab',
margin: '0 0 0 20'
}`

Comment: Good tip! To group tabs, you may also use a negative right margin. This will make them partly overlap.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way through the component to do that, you'll have to override the tab's margin in CSS, e.g.:

```
ul.x-tab-strip li {
   margin-left: 8px;
}
```

If you only need it to apply to certain tabs then give them ids or special classes and adjust the CSS accordingly.